# Python & BS4 pagination loop

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping and I'm trying to do it on this page https://www.metrocuadrado.com/bogota.

The idea is to extract all the information. So far I have been able to do it with only one page but I do not know how to do it with pagination. Is there any way to do it based on the code I already have?

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

# opening up connection, grabbing html
my_url = 'https://www.metrocuadrado.com/bogota'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# html parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")


# grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"detail_wrap"})

filename = "metrocuadrado.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers= "propertytype, businestype, cityname, neighborhood, description, price, area\n"

f.write(headers)


for container in containers:
    property_type = container[propertytype]
    busines_type = container[businestype]
    city_name = container[cityname]
    neighborhood_location = container[neighborhood]
    description = container.div.a.img["alt"]

    price_container = container.findAll("span",{"itemprop":"price"})
    price =  price_container[0].text

    area_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"m2"})
    area = area_container[0].p.span.text

    print("property_type: " + property_type)
    print("busines_type: " + busines_type)
    print("city_name: " + city_name)
    print("neighborhood_location: " + neighborhood_location)
    print("description: " + description)
    print("price: " + price)
    print("area: " + area)

f.write(property_type + "," + busines_type + "," + city_name + "," + neighborhood_location + "," + description.replace(",", "|") + "," + price + "," + area + "\n")

f.close()
```

Comment: There are post requests made in network traffic e.g. https://www.metrocuadrado.com/search/list/ajax?&mnrogarajes=&mnrobanos=&mnrocuartos=&mtiempoconstruido=&marea=&mvalorarriendo=&mvalorventa=&mciudad=bogota&mubicacion=&mtiponegocio=venta-nuevo&mtipoinmueble=&mzona=&msector=&mbarrio=&selectedLocationCategory=1&selectedLocationFilter=mciudad&mestadoinmueble=&madicionales=&orderBy=&sortType=&companyType=&companyName=&midempresa=&mgrupo=&mgrupoid=&mbasico=&currentPage=2&totalPropertiesCount=121901&totalUsedPropertiesCount=121568&totalNewPropertiesCount=333&sfh=1

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to scrape each page (likely in a loop), do this by figuring out what the call is to get page 2, page 3 etc.  You can try to figure that out by looking at the page source code or using developer tools from your browser and looking at the network calls.